# Getting the error while querying in Maria DB

Tags: mariadb

While running above query in **mairadb**, I am getting the error :

```
 update employee_details set HireDate = 2004-12-02  where Emp_FName =
 'aarat';
```

Comment: what error .. ?

Comment: sorry, now query is executing but value of that column is not getting change?

Answer (score 3):

The date should be in quotes:

```
 update employee_details set HireDate = '2004-12-02'  where Emp_FName =
 'aarat';
```